# CORS is required to use video.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, cors, video.js

I use this package [node-ytdl](https://github.com/fent/node-ytdl-core) to get a direct link of any youtube video.

When I start playing the source using a regular HTML5  tag it works with cors() on the [express](https://expressjs.com/) server.

but once I start using [video.js](https://github.com/videojs/video.js/) to run the video it gives me cors error, this CORS error get working with Google Chrome CORS extension.

Idk is this needme to have a copy of video.js package and tweak it or there's a known work around ?

Answer (score -1):

The CORS issue isn't really specific to your video JS file. This has been explained properly [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7067966/how-to-allow-cors) .

Comment: the video is working without video.js so it's the packages' problem

Answer (score -2):

Try adding the following to your Express app to allow cors:

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
    next();
});
```